# Function: return True/False based on presence of substring in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, substring

I'm working on CoderByte's beginner JavaScript challenge. My code works in the "true" cases, but as soon as I add an else clause to handle the "false" cases, it begins to misbehave.

**The challenge:** *write a function ABCheck(str) to take the **str** parameter being passed and return the string true if the characters a and b are separated by exactly 3 places anywhere in the string at least once (ie. "lane borrowed" would result in true because there is exactly three characters between a and b). Otherwise return the string false.*

**Observations:** if I remove the  portion, the code works no matter what.  But if I add a clause to handle the false cases, I feel like the counter breaks. For example, with the false portion, it works if (AxxB) is at the very beginning of the string, but it then returns false even if it's later in the string (zAxxB). Perhaps the counter is breaking, or I have the else clause in an incorrect spot? Something along those lines.

Thanks for any tips and for being patient with a beginner!

```
function ABCheck(str) { 

    //normalizes the string into an array without spaces
    var arr = str.toLowerCase().split("").join("").replace( /\s/g, "")

    //searches the entire string for the substring and returns true if it's found
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].indexOf('a') != -1 && arr[i+3].indexOf('b') != -1){
            return true
        }

        //returns false if substring doesn't exist in string
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
}

ABCheck(readline());
```

Comment: This seems like a good job for a regexp.

Comment: What is the point of `.split("").join("")`? `join` turns it back into a string.

Comment: Why are you using `indexOf()`? `arr[i]` is a single character, so you can just write `arr[i] == 'a'`

Comment: The problem statement says that the function is supposed to return the **string** `true` or `false`. You're returning a boolean, not a string.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. You use `indexOf()` when you're searching for something that can be anywhere in a string. But when you have a single character, there's only one place it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because for the first time only when it doesn't find the condition `arr[i].indexOf('a') != -1 && arr[i+3].indexOf('b') != -1` to be `true` it returns `false` and function is over.

```
function ABCheck(str) {
    var arr = str.toLowerCase().split("").join("").replace( /\s/g, "")
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       if(arr[i].indexOf('a') != -1 && arr[i+3].indexOf('b') != -1){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So it will check any time if the condition will be true it will return `true` other wise after the `for` loop it will return `false`.

**Note:-** I think `.split("").join("")` is unnecessary work.

Comment: This did it, thank you. I had actually tried moving it outside of the loop prior to posting, but I was still using the "else{return false}" statement with it instead of just "return false". Split and Join are pretty new to me, I'll be sure to go back and find out exactly what they're doing. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Regarding .split() and .join(), aren't spaces counted? And if not, why? I removed everything after the toLowerCase method and it still worked. I even tried "testing" this by printing out <arr> and it indeed had spaces, eg [t,e,s,t, ,t,e,s,t]. I feel like this would throw off the [i+3] part. Does this shifting up and down the array not view whitespace as characters? Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `return false;` **out** of `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){...}` loop.

Comment: I thought of and tried this, but it gives me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else". Thoughts? Thank you. Edit: I was still using "else" instead of just "return false." Doing that while moving it outside the loop fixed it.

Comment: You dont need 'else' anymore! 'else' comes only with 'if' clause!